# SQL error, getting time difference between 2 dates. One in the database and the other is current time

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote the following query which returns an SQL error:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, SELECT(attempttime) FROM table ORDER BY testtime DESC LIMIT 1, now());
```

The SELECT inside, gets the DATETIME, the time of user attempt. I want to find the time passed since the last user attempt. E.g. 
Between now and last attempttime it's been 4 days.

Comment: Your code is SQL Server but your tag is MySQL.  Also, edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, the code would look something like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), MAX(attempttime))
FROM table t
```